# Get a value from mdInput

Tags: angular, typescript, material-design, angular-material2

So I have a `md-input` and some button.

```
<md-input-container >
   <input mdInput #myInput name="myInput" type="password" placeholder="Yeah">
</md-input-container>
<button md-raised-button (click)="authenticate(myInput)">Start</button>
```

This button sends the whole `md-input`. I fill in my input and that's what I'm getting when I click the button

```
<input _ngcontent-uqn-44="" mdinput="" name="myInput" placeholder="Yeah" type="password" ng-reflect-placeholder="Yeah" ng-reflect-type="password" class="mat-input-element" ng-reflect-id="md-input-1" id="md-input-1" aria-describedby="">
```

I don't see any property/attribute which contains the value I pasted in Input. So how could I get the value?  Like `myInput.value`?

Comment: are you getting any errors ? if so update the screenshot of it

Comment: Solved. Dont know where was the problem

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with your code, there may be something else which is causing issue.

```
<md-input-container >
    <input mdInput #myInput name="myInput" type="password" placeholder="Yeah">
 </md-input-container>
 {{myInput.value}}
```

Check this [Plunker!](https://plnkr.co/edit/boPkdSO47oBtTRowkhja?p=preview)