# angular6: passing value of the input field to the component

Tags: angular, parameter-passing, angular6

I am trying to pass value of the input field to the component class. But it does not seem to be working. Please find the code below:

todoinput.component.html

```
<mat-card>
  <form>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input matInput type="text" name="todo" placeholder="Enter a todo">
    </mat-form-field>
    &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="button" (click)="addTodo(todo.value)">Add Todo
    </button>
  </form>
</mat-card>
```

todoinput.component.ts

```
  addTodo(text) {
    this._todosService.addTodo({
      text: text,
    }).subscribe((todo) => {
      return this.newTodo.emit(todo);
    })
  }
```

But clicking on the button throws the error below:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at Object.eval [as handleEvent] (TodoinputComponent.html:7)
    at handleEvent (core.js:10258)
```

I am using angular material framework for rendering the elements. Could anyone let me know what am I doing wrong here ?

Thanks

Comment: instead name="todo" try #todo

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42513925/get-a-value-from-mdinput

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try to add `#todo` to the input. After that angular should be able to acces to the right input. Without that it gets undefined variable instead.

```
<mat-card>
  <form>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input #todo matInput type="text" name="todo" placeholder="Enter a todo">
    </mat-form-field>
    &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="button" (click)="addTodo(todo.value)">Add Todo
    </button>
  </form>
</mat-card>
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative that I think might be easier to work with is to have a backing field and bind to it:

html:

```
<mat-card>   
  <form>
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <input [(ngModel)]="todo" matInput type="text" name="todo" placeholder="Enter a todo">
    </mat-form-field>
    &nbsp; &nbsp;
    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="button" (click)="addTodo()">Add Todo
    </button>   
  </form> 
</mat-card>
```

ts

```
todo = '';

addTodo() {
    if (!this.todo) {
       return;
    }

    this._todosService.addTodo({
      text: this.todo,
    }).subscribe((todo) => {
      this.todo = '';
      return this.newTodo.emit(todo);
    })
  }
```

This way its easier to do things like validate they entered a value, and reset the field to empty after a successful submit.

Answer (score -1):

Use #todo in element:

```
<input matInput type="text" name="todo" #todo placeholder="Enter a todo">
```

And use:

```
{{ todo.value }}
```

Comment: Using `#todo` is correct on the `input`. For the `button`, continue to use `(click)="addTodo(todo.value)"` without the interpolation syntax `{{ ... }}`